# Azure Function works but reports "409 The specified container already exists"

Tags: azure-functions

In my Azure Function which doesn't have any Azure Storage code I'm getting the following warning in Application Insights.

```
Error response [15fd74...ec3601] 409 The specified container already exists. (00.0s)
Server:Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id:b72b1...f5-26564f000000
x-ms-client-request-id:15fd74...0ec3601
x-ms-version:2020-08-04
x-ms-error-code:ContainerAlreadyExists
Date:Mon, 21 Feb 2022 07:33:56 GMT
Content-Length:230
Content-Type:application/xml
```

I think it's reasonable to assume this is something to do with the storage account that the Azure Functions use to record their state etc.

SDK version azurefunctions: 4.1.3.17473

Is there a way to debug and/or resolve the issue?

Comment: I've created https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2166

Comment: Same problem here. Did you solve that somehow?

Comment: I've used "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="4.3.1" and I don't see the warnings.

Answer (score 9):

It's apparently a bug in the functions SDK.  If you add "Azure.Core": "Error" to the logLevel setting in the host.json file, then you will suppress it.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "excludedTypes": "Request"
        }
      },
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Warning",
        "Custom": "Information",
        "Function": "Information", // dependency telemetry, used to analyzing dependencies and their performance
        "Host.Results": "Information", // request telemetry, used for analyzing execution performance
        "Azure.Core": "Error" // suppressing sdk blob warnings 
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I found this after wondering why I'd spent so much on Log Analytics over the past few months. Turns out this has been spamming Insights with these messages.

Comment: Helped me as well to get rid of the "409 The specified container already exists" message. net7.0, v4 functions

Comment: This error still exists after 2 years? smh